# jQueryでの変数定義について

Tags: jquery

jQueryを勉強している者です。

変数を定義するときに、変数名に＄が付く場合と付かない場合があるのですが、
どのような違いがあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

完全に任意ですが、**慣習的に**jQueryインスタンスを持つ変数の名前に$をプレフィックスとしてつけることがあります。
これによって変数が持つのがjQueryインスタンスであることはひと目でわかります。

例:

```
const name = 'john'
const $foo = $('#foo')

$foo.text(name)
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
jQueryインスタンスを持つとは、どういうことでしょうか？
質問が初歩すぎるかもしれませんが、、、
教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 例で示しているよう、jQueryで要素を選択したりして生成したjQueryのオブジェクトです。といってもどの程度の説明が必要なのかなんともで私にはうまく説明できなさそうですが…… https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35782/ https://qiita.com/yassh/items/056162f3a2ffb32eca59#jquery%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。大変たすかりました！